# How do I wipe a USB drive using dd on cygwin on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, cygwin, dd, file-shredding

I am trying to use [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) to wipe a usb drive using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) on Windows. What should I use for the `of` argument?

```
dd if=/dev/null of=?
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that writing `/dev/null` to a block device will do nothing.  Block device meaning `/dev/sdc` not `/dev/sdc1` sdc1 refers to the first partition, not the entire device.

You want to use:

```
/dev/zero
```

Or:

```
/dev/urandom
```

Answer (score 5):

Cygwin uses [following device mapping](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) for harddisk-like devices:

```
POSIX device name     Internal NT device name

/dev/sda          \device\harddisk0\partition0  (whole disk)
/dev/sda1         \device\harddisk0\partition1  (first partition)
...
/dev/sda15        \device\harddisk0\partition15 (fifteenth partition)

/dev/sdb          \device\harddisk1\partition0
/dev/sdb1         \device\harddisk1\partition1

[up to]

/dev/sddx         \device\harddisk127\partition0
/dev/sddx1        \device\harddisk127\partition1
...
/dev/sddx15       \device\harddisk127\partition15
```

You can see NT device names in Disk Management in Management Console.

Also use `/dev/zero` instead of `/dev/null` as input.

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` will give you `Win-Drive <--> /dev/*` mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Cygwin has the same core commands as a Unix/Linux install, you can us [`df`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html)—which tells you how much free space (disk free) is available on your devices but also gives you nice filesystem data—you can use for situations like this.

For example, here is the output of [`df`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html) from my Mac OS X terminal:

```
Filesystem    512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   975093952  135358704  839223248    14%  16983836 104902906   14%   /
devfs                381        381          0   100%       660         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0          0          0   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0          0          0   100%         0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk2s2  3906357344 2097411968 1808945376    54% 262176494 226118172   54%   /Volumes/Moe
/dev/disk1s2   235154168  118616008  116538160    51%  14826999  14567270   50%   /Volumes/Larry
/dev/disk1s3  3670941032 2100018304 1570922728    58% 262502286 196365341   57%   /Volumes/Curly
```

Note the last three entries that show mount points as well as the file system you are connected to. So let’s say I want to erase `/Volumes/Curly` to replace him at some point with data from a place called `/Volumes/Shemp`, I would erase all of the data on the drive and then run this [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1s3/wipe_file.txt
```

And just so you understand what that command does, `if` indicates what the input file is (get it, `if`) and `of` indicates the output file (similarly… get it, `of`) and that’s that. And I am using `/dev/zero` instead of `/dev/null` since `/dev/null` is an input destination for data you don’t need while `/dev/zero` is an output source for a stream of `0` characters.

So when you run that [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) command the contents of `/dev/zero` (which is just an endless stream of `0` characters) will be copied to `wipe_file.txt` on `/dev/disk1s3/`. Meaning a new file named `wipe_file.txt` will be created that grows & grows until it fills the full capacity of `/dev/disk1s3/`.

But depending on how paranoid you are about data, you can also change `if` to be `random` like this:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/disk1s3/wipe_file.txt
```

Using `zero` will explicitly just fill `wipe_file.txt` with `0` characters while `random` will fill the file with random characters. Note that filling a file with random data will require more computing power than just filling the file with nothing, so the `random` method will take longer. But if you are worried about prying eyes recovering data that might be the best thing to assuredly destroy already erased data on a drive.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, seriously informative.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable source for drive-letter-mapping for me is a combination of diskpart, blkid and /proc/partitions

```
    user@system:~$ diskpart
    
    Microsoft DiskPart-Version 10.0.19041.964
    
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
    Auf Computer: SYSTEM
    
    DISKPART> list disk
    
      Datenträger ###  Status         Größe    Frei     Dyn  GPT
      ---------------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
      Datenträger 0    Online         1863 GB  1024 KB        *
      Datenträger 1    Online            9 TB  1024 KB        *
      Datenträger 2    Kein Medium        0 B      0 B
      Datenträger 3    Kein Medium        0 B      0 B
      Datenträger 4    Kein Medium        0 B      0 B
      Datenträger 5    Kein Medium        0 B      0 B
      Datenträger 6    Kein Medium        0 B      0 B
      Datenträger 7    Online         1863 GB  1863 GB
    
    DISKPART> select disk 1
    
    Datenträger 1 ist jetzt der gewählte Datenträger.
    
    DISKPART> list part
    
      Partition ###  Typ               Größe    Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
      Partition 1    Reserviert          15 MB    17 KB
      Partition 2    Primär               9 TB    16 MB
    
    DISKPART>
    
    user@system:~$ cat /proc/partitions
    major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts
        8     0 1953514584 sda
        8     1    113664 sda1
        8     2     16384 sda2
        8     3 1952839766 sda3   C:\
        8     4    541696 sda4
        8    16 9766436864 sdb
        8    17     16367 sdb1
        8    18 9766418432 sdb2   D:\
        8    32         0 sdc
        8    48         0 sdd
        8    64         0 sde
        8    80         0 sdf
        8    96         0 sdg
        8   112 1953514584 sdh
        8   128   8388608 sdi
        8   129   8385536 sdi1

user@system:~$ /sbin/blkid.exe
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="2A05-C09D" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="087A36A47A368E86" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda4: UUID="A080B84E80B82CA2" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Data" UUID="1864245164243442" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="PortableBaseLayer" UUID="6278D53678D50A25" TYPE="ntfs"
```

While I would definitely prefer a device list with real drive names (Seagate ST2000DM001 or something like that) I can easily work out the drive mapping by checking the output of the previous commands. And make sure to double and tripple check, nothing is more hilarious than whipping your C:-Drive.